# How to make Google form submission sort into separate sheets?

Tags: excel, spreadsheet

I can only get this to sort automatically when I input the text manually into the cell. I've tried changing to `OnFormSubmit` but no luck. How can I rewrite this to have Google Docs automatically sort the form-submitted answers to separate tabs?

```
function onEdit(event) {
  // assumes source data in sheet named Needed
  // target sheet of move to named Acquired
  // test column with yes/no is col 4 or D
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var r = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveRange();

  if(s.getName() == "Inbox" && r.getColumn() == 6 && r.getValue() == "Los Angeles") {
  var row = r.getRow();
  var numColumns = s.getLastColumn();
  var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Los Angeles");
  var target = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1);
  s.getRange(row, 1, 1, numColumns).moveTo(target);
  s.deleteRow(row)

  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Dont write the sorted sheet data manually. Instead use a single QUERY formula per sheet. With it you can filter sort grouo and pivot your data as you like.